# Unable to send Event Grid Event from Azure function App using User Managed Identity Credentials

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, azure-functions, azure-eventgrid

While trying to send data to Azure EventGrid using UserManagedIdentity Credential, it is throwing `ClassNotFoundException: com.azure.core.util.tracing.TracerProvider` .

```java
import com.azure.identity.ManagedIdentityCredentialBuilder;
import com.azure.messaging.eventgrid.EventGridEvent;
import com.azure.messaging.eventgrid.EventGridPublisherClient;
import com.azure.messaging.eventgrid.EventGridPublisherClientBuilder;
import com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential;

TokenCredential managedIdentityCredentialUserAssigned = new ManagedIdentityCredentialBuilder().clientId(System.getenv("MANAGED_IDENTITY_CLIENT_ID")).build();
EventGridPublisherClient<EventGridEvent> eventGridEventClient = new EventGridPublisherClientBuilder()
     .endpoint(System.getenv("EVENTGRID_SYNC_TOPIC_ENDPOINT")).credential(managedIdentityCredentialUserAssigned).buildEventGridEventPublisherClient();
```

```java
Exception: ClassNotFoundException: com.azure.core.util.tracing.TracerProvider
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/azure/core/util/tracing/TracerProvider
    at com.azure.messaging.eventgrid.EventGridPublisherClientBuilder.buildAsyncClient(EventGridPublisherClientBuilder.java:204)
    at com.azure.messaging.eventgrid.EventGridPublisherClientBuilder.buildClient(EventGridPublisherClientBuilder.java:232)
    at com.azure.messaging.eventgrid.EventGridPublisherClientBuilder.buildEventGridEventPublisherClient(EventGridPublisherClientBuilder.java:393)
    at com.cie.poc.managed.identity.function.service.ManagedIdentityEventGridService.sendEvent(ManagedIdentityEventGridService.java:39)
    at com.cie.poc.managed.identity.function.SaveDataToBlob.apply(SaveDataToBlob.java:56)
    at com.cie.poc.managed.identity.function.SaveDataToBlob.apply(SaveDataToBlob.java:22)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.invokeFunctionAndEnrichResultIfNecessary(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:897)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.invokeFunction(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:853)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.doApply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:708)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.context.catalog.SimpleFunctionRegistry$FunctionInvocationWrapper.apply(SimpleFunctionRegistry.java:551)
    at org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.azure.FunctionInvoker.handleRequest(FunctionInvoker.java:129)
    at com.cie.poc.managed.identity.function.SaveDataToBlobHandler.run(SaveDataToBlobHandler.java:32)
    ... 18 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.azure.core.util.tracing.TracerProvider
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 30 more
```

hese are the related dependencies and their versions defined in `pom.xml` of my azure function app.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-messaging-eventgrid</artifactId>
    <version>4.18.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-eventgrid</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.35.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring Boot Version: 2.7.8, Java version: 11

Kindly help if you know how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your Azure Java SDK version?

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere these are the related dependencies and their versions defined in pom.xml of my azure function app. 

                <dependency>
      <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
      <artifactId>azure-messaging-eventgrid</artifactId>
      <version>4.18.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
     <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
   <artifactId>azure-eventgrid</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.0</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this issue after using *azure-core* with *1.42.0* version.I added the following dependency in pom.xml file of my function app.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.42.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I previously had *azure-core 1.35.0* which doesn't contain the TracerProvider class.

Comment: Were you missing this dependency altogether?

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere No, I had 1.35.0 version of this dependency which doesn't contains TracerProvider